# Change LAN MAC on DD-WRT router for swap

Tags: dd-wrt, mac-address

DD-WRT's interface shows options to change the WAN and WLAN MAC but not the LAN MAC.

I have two identical DD-WRT routers with identical configurations on them but since the LAN MAC is not the same, things like Windows workgroup or Linux samba reject authentication through the new router.

Comment: Any ARP entries should (eventually) time out and the hosts should then get the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The command that will work on DD-WRT is:

`ip link set dev {interface-name} address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

from a root prompt via telnet or ssh.